# Unable to quit from python script using CTRL+C in Win10

Tags: python, server, python-asyncio, exit, keyboardinterrupt

With the following code I'm unable to quit using CTRL+C after running it. I also tried to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` from different code positions without success. I'm using Windows 10 x64 and Python 3.7.6.

```
async def handle_req(self, reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
    try:
        data = await reader.read()
        msg = data.decode()

        addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

        print(f"Received {msg!r} from {addr!r}")

        writer.write("Res".encode())
        writer.write_eof()
        await writer.drain()

        writer.close()
    except OSError:
        print("Client endpoint unreachable")


async def main():

    try:

        server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_req, "127.0.0.1", 9000)
        addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print(f'Serving on {addr}')

        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
        server.wait_closed()
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Because you are catching the keyboard interruption and preventing an exit.

Comment: @zerohedge getting downvoted but this isn't the solution, the proposed one doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

your using exception for the keyboard interruptions so try import sys and following lines

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.stop()
    loop.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: The server gets stuck at the read, upon receiving a message it is able to catch the interrupt and quit

Comment: No errors at all, it just catches the interrupt and exit, even without `sys.exit()`